# angular-cli was not updated and ng serve does not work

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I want to update my angular-cli. I am using:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

but I get this console errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\Users\\Saeed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ng' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \'C:\\Users\\Saeed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ng\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Saeed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ng' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-07T07_21_17_386Z-debug.log
```

and then when I want to run `ng serve` I get these errors:

`bash: /c/Users/Saeed/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng: Permission denied`

What should I do? Any help?

I also deleted the npm cache, but it didn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any angular app running? Try rebooting your system and run your command again.
The files might be locked by a running app which causes your error above.